# How can I instantiate a new dataclass instance in Python without supplying parameters?

Tags: python

I want to create a data class instance and supply values later.

How can I do this?

```
def create_trade_data():
    trades = []
    td = TradeData()
    td.Symbol='New'
    trades.append(td)
    return trades
```

DataClass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TradeData:
    Symbol : str
    ExecPrice : float
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the attributes optional by giving them a default value `None`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TradeData:
    Symbol: str = None
    ExecPrice: float = None
```

Then your `create_trade_data` function would return

```
[TradeData(Symbol='New', ExecPrice=None)]
```

Now, I chose `None` as the default value to indicate a lack of content. Of course, you could choose more sensible defaults like in the other answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers no particular reason, just thought of them as `Optional` values. And certainly, they could be any default value, but since I didn't know which defaults would have been sensible, marking them as `None` seemed a good sentinel value. Will expand the answer later.

Answer (score 1):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TradeData:
    Symbol : str = ''
    ExecPrice : float = 0.0
```

With the = operator you can assign default values.
There is the [field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) method which is used for mutable values, like list.